# Doubt regarding Hypergeometric Random Variable

Tags: probability-distributions

I was reading probability from Sheldon Ross and found below example.

A purchaser of electrical components buys them in lots of size 10. It is his policy to inspect 3 components from a lot and to accept the lot if all the 3 are nondefective. If 30 percent of the lots have 4 defective components and 70 percent have only 1, what proportion of lots does the purchaser reject?

And the solution is presented like this

Let A denote the event that the purchaser accepts a lot. Now,

P(A)= $P(A|lot\,has\,4\,defectives\,)\frac{3}{10}+P(A|lot\,has\,1\,defective)\frac{7}{10}$

I understood the conditional probability part but why they have multiplied it with $\frac{3}{10}$ in the first part and $\frac{7}{10}$ in the second?

Answer (score 1):

Because those are the proportions for the two cases that are specified in the question. ($30\%$ is $\frac3{10}$ and $70\%$ is $\frac7{10}$.) It's the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) (applied to proportions instead of probabilities).

Comment: $$\begin{split}\mathsf P(A) &= \mathsf P(A\mid D{=}4)~\mathsf P(D{=}4)+\mathsf P(A\mid D{=}1)~\mathsf P(D{=}1)\\ &= \qquad~~\mathsf P(A\mid D{=}4)~\tfrac 3{10}+\mathsf P(A\mid D{=}1)~\tfrac 7{10}\end{split}$$